# How to SUM all the values on a SQL database column and show the total as a TextView?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sum

i'm making a financial app and the user inserts expenses that are record on a SQL database. what i want to do is retrieve the total sum of those expenses and show it on a Textview. I already search everything but i still can't get it right, maybe its  my stupidity but i realy can't.

This is the  code where i create the method to get the total to the TextView

```
SQLiteActone actone = new SQLiteActone(this);
    actone.open();
    String returnedTotal = actone.getTotal();
    actone.close();
    tvTotalact1.setText(returnedTotal);
```

and this is the code of that method:

```
public String getTotal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT SUM(KEY_VALUEACTONE) FROM DATABASE_TABLEONE ", null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        return cursor;
```

I know that return cursor; does not work and its an erro, but i had return null; and i know people would just say that the null was the problem.

Please help me to get this right! 
Ty all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return int and set to textview like:

```
int sum=getTotal();
text_view_object.setText(""+sum);
```

and modified code:

```
public int getTotal() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int sum=0;
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT SUM(KEY_VALUEACTONE) FROM DATABASE_TABLEONE ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getcount()>0) {
        sum=cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return sum;
   }
```

like if this help otherwise comment that i can help you.

Comment: i tried your code, the thing is, with the int sum=getTotal(); i need to create the method for getTotal(); in the private method it creates what should i put? it comes as return 0; but that does not give the desire result

Comment: did you check database that you have inserted all values correctly in database??

Comment: the values inserted in th DB are ok !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

Md Mohsin

The problem with your code was this:

```
int sum=getTotal();
text_view_object.setText(""+sum);
```

since i have to call the Database too get that method to work i need to go like this:

```
SQLiteActone actone = new SQLiteActone(this);
    actone.open();
    int sum=getTotal();
    actone.close();
    tvTotalact1.setText(""+sum);
```

But for it to work it i need this:

instead of int sum =getTotal(); i need to call the method by the reference i made first, int sum = actone.getTotal();

once again ty for your help